# For loop, keeps counting up

Tags: python

I'm attempting to write a script that counts the number of occurences of a given list of tokens in a collection of files. 
So far I have the following:

```
for text in posts:
   words = wordpunct_tokenize (text)
   tags = nltk.pos_tag (words)
   list_tags=defaultdict(int)
   for a,b in tags:
      tags3.append(b)
   for t in tags3:
      if t in tags_list:
          list_tags[t]+=1
   print list_tags
```

problem is that the program does not purge the tokens if found in the previous post, and is just counting up per post.
At the last post it claims to have found 70.000 occurences of a given token in a post of 500 words.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appended a *tuple* to your list:

```
list_words.append(("foo", "bar", "tiger"))
```

Because you split `text` into individual words, there will *never* be a tuple with three words in `words` for which `w in list_words` is `True`. As such your claim that your count goes up to 70.000 can not be true, the code, *as shown*, would only ever give you an empty `list_words2` dictionary.

Just define the list directly:

```
list_words = ["foo", "bar", "tiger"]
```

or better still, use a `set` for fast membership testing:

```
set_words = {"foo", "bar", "tiger"}
```

Your code will be much easier to read if you used `collections.Counter()` instead:

```
from collections import Counter    

set_words = {"foo", "bar", "tiger"}

for text in posts:
    list_words2 = Counter(word for word in text.split() if word in set_words)
    print list_words2
```

---

Update for your changed question with real code:

You are updating a list `tags3` with new tagged words, by appending them without clearing the list. With each `text` you process, `tags3` grows, but you then process `tags3` *from the start* for each iteration in your loop. Your 70.000 is a factorial number; first you process 400 tokens, then you process another 300 tags for a total of 700, then you process 100 additional words, so now you loop over `tags` 800 times, etc.

Clear, `tags3` to avoid this problem (e.g. `tags3 = []` *inside* the loop), or better still, loop directly over `tags` and do *not* append at all:

```
for text in posts:
   words = wordpunct_tokenize (text)
   tags = nltk.pos_tag (words)
   list_tags = Counter(b for a, b in tags if b in tags_list)
   print list_tags
```

Do make sure that `tags_list` is really a set, otherwise the `b in tags_list` test has to loop over the `tags_list` elements for each and every tag.

Comment: So the mystery is how it was counting 70,000 occurances

Comment: @gnibbler: getting there, showing that the code in question cannot **possibly** add a counter up to 70,000.

Comment: @joneshf: I suspect the `if` statement has been simplified, we are missing something here.

Comment: I give you the +1, but really this question is unanswerable with the given code :)

Comment: @gnibbler: there are variations of  `if w in some_list or other_list:` that'd be `True` all the time; I suspect the original code has something like that.

Comment: It seems that it was this snippet of code that counts up to 70.000,
seemed similar to me, but it apparently isn't:
for text in blogs:
    words = wordpunct_tokenize (text)
    tags = nltk.pos_tag (words)
    list_tags=defaultdict(int)
    for a,b in tags:
        tags3.append(b)
    for t in tags3:
        if t in tags_list:
            list_tags[t]+=1
    print list_tags

Comment: @Nikolaas: Please edit your question to update it with more information. It is almost impossible to make out your code in a comment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is brilliant. The only problem I still have is that it seems to be ordered by highest frequency, while every token needs to be ordered in the same order as tags_list with a 0 for tags not found.

Comment: @Nikolaas: Then you are using the wrong tool to count items; use an `OrderedDict` in that case as standard dictionaries (including `defaultdict` and `Counter`) do not define an order.

Comment: @Nikolaas: `Counter()` objects *display* the contents reverse sorted by frequency, but otherwise there is no ordering to rely on.